# Attribute to choose while customizing Css Selector in selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium

I am trying to login a website and trying to click on login button. HTML Node for that button is

```html
<button data-purpose="header-login" type="button" class="btn btn-quaternary">Log In</button>
```

My code is

```js
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.udemy.com");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[type='button']"))).click();
```

```
O/P- `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: button[type='button'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

However when in code when I replace `cssSelector("button[type='button']")` from `cssSelector("button[class='btn btn-quaternary']")`, it works completely fine.

is **type** is the wrong atrribute choice?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is correct but the CSS selector you are using point to the multiple elements as shown below:**

```
By.cssSelector("button[type='button']"))
```

[image]

2) However When you use the below **cssSelector("button[class='btn btn-quaternary']")** it points to the specific login button that you are targeting.

[image]

There is one more alternative way by using the XPath (Not recommended as position can be changed):

```
(//button[@type='button'])[4]
```